# My friend's WiFi switch is greyed out. How can I fix it?

Tags: wifi, iphone, settings

He can't turn on WiFi at all. Tried resetting network settings, but haven't restored. Not jailbroken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This most likely means that his Wifi chip/antenna/thing is "burnt out". You can most likely get it replaced at an Apple Store, or through a 3rd party Apple approved technician.

Comment: Ok. I'll talk to him and see.